# What is the proper way to edit files in the /sys filesystem and have them stick

Tags: usb, bluetooth, hardware, system, devices

I was able to get my BlueTooth mouse to stop lagging with the command:

```sh
echo 300 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/power/autosuspend
```

However, I believe that this change will be lost upon reboot.

I understand the concept of the `/sys` directory being an abstraction of the hardware on the computer and by writing to this pretend file I am actually changing some runtime? kernel? parameter.

I am also aware of commands like `sysctl` that work on this system, and `.rules` files that *I think* would be used to persistently set such values, but have not been able to figure out how to actually implement it after hours of searching. I am probably totally off track for all I know.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why ask the question when you have not rebooted to see if this even happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `echo 300 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/power/autosuspend`
>
> However I believe that this change will be lost upon reboot.

I would create a `.rules` file for `udev` to automatically set the value when the device is added. E.g., file `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-bluetooth-mouse-autosuspend.rules` containing:

```
ACTION=="add", \
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14", \
ATTR{power/autosuspend}="300"
```

Now reboot and check if the value is set to "300":

```
$ cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/power/autosuspend
300
```

Note that this rule will be applied to that specific USB port even if you plug in a different device other than the mouse. It is probably a better idea to check output of `udevadm info -a -p /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14` for **`ATTR{product}=="xxx"`** and/or **`ATTR{serial}=="xxx"`** that you can include in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-bluetooth-mouse-autosuspend.rules` file. This will ensure the rule matches only your bluetooth mouse.